# How do I prevent, stop, or kill JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

How do I prevent this JavaScript function from executing.

I have a js function that is causing a serious issue and I am not able to remove nor modify it source. I would like to know if it is possible to simply prevent, stop, or kill the function in order that it is not executed till I resolve the issue.

So somewhere inside the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
problem_func();
//--></script>
```

And all I want is to stop that function from execution placing a stopper inside the header or external js.

Any advice?

**HERE IS THE LIVE EXAMPLE, HOW TO STOP THAT? http://jsbin.com/uxalag/3**

Comment: @Mörre I still see the bad code executed. Did you modify smth?

Comment: You need to place the "overwrite-function" BETWEEN where the "bad" function is declared and where it is invoked. If that is not possible, because both locations are in the same JS file, there is no solution (worth thinking about) for your problem. Oh and by the way - omit those HTML comments from the script tags. We are long past browsers that needed this (that was for Netscape 4 and IE 5 or so).

Comment: @Mörre mate, I have an idea but I am not sure if that would help. What if I create function inside header to look foor <script> tag and wipe its innerHTML. Would that make any effect?

Comment: No, it would not work - at that point the browser does not know about any of the not yet parsed tags. I just tried it to be sure, in teh first script tag document.getElementsByTagName("script") only returns that first script tag, in the second script tag it returns the first and the current (2nd) one, etc. So you cannot manipulate any tags below the one you are at during loading. But an interesting idea :-) (not recommended, but interesting)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you know the function name, you can replace it with a function that does nothing.
After the script tag of the source js file use this:

```
window.FunctionName=function(){return false;};
```

Comment: If the function is in global namespace (and not hidden inside an anonymous function) he can overwrite it from ANYWHERE, no need to edit the sources. This replaces it in *memory*.

Comment: as Morre said, this has nothing to do with the source, it modifies the function in the memory

Comment: the idea is to prevent it, if I am going to put it after the bad function then it still will get executed? Makes sense? Coming up with example in a second.

Comment: of course it will be executed, but your version of the function that returns a false instead of the original function. ain't that the same as not calling it at all?

Comment: `JavaScript` executes top-down. Thus your re-definition will not work if the `problem_func` is executed within the script source that he cannot modify! Your redefinition will come later, after the damage is done...

Comment: @Mörre could you please check the example http://jsbin.com/uxalag/3 to see if that is something you mean?

Comment: Oh, this is more complicated then. What exactly does this function do?

Comment: @Kheu it is a live2support chat that document writes its external code.

Comment: Can't you attach an event on the document that clears this code when written?

Comment: Well, as Xander said, the overwrite-method only works if that func. isn't immediately called. My suggestion only works for functions executed in the next "tick" (event loop), obviously if execution is immediate overwriting it is impossible. Inthat case the answer to your question is "you can't", or possibly a very ugly, horrible hack is a possibility but let's not go there, please :)

Comment: Thank you @Mörre it is very sad though. Thank you for your and others help

Comment: who said the scope is the `window`...sometimes you have no access to the scope.

Answer (score 5):

Just overwrite it

for example if a `function abc() { ..... }` causing you problem you can overwrite it with an empty body.

```
function abc() {  }
```