# .toLowerCase() of undefined failing silently in background - but code still works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Obviously, it's not good to let things fail in the background but it seems like it's the only way to get this example to work consistently. How would I work around this?

Sometimes, I need to check a div with a data-attribute on some pages and add a class if it's a match. Other times, I need to check if the URL contains a string and append it to a header.

On the pages where there is no data-attribute to check, it throws:

> scripts.js:88 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Since there is no data-attribute to check.

Everything looks like this:

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
// highlight relevant menu item
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("stackoverflow") > -1) {
    $(".main-header--light").text("STACKOVERFLOW");
  }
  var tagName = $("#content").data("category").toLowerCase();
  $(".nav-item").each(function() {
    var menuItem = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    if (menuItem == tagName) {
      console.log(this);
      $(this).addClass("subnav-active");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>HEADER - <span class="main-header--light"></span></h1>

<div id="content"></div>
<ul>
<li class="nav-item">11</li>
<li class="nav-item">2</li>
<li class="nav-item">34</li>
<li class="nav-item">44</li>
</ul>
```

This code works fine as is and when there is a match in `window.location.href.indexOf` the header updates and when there is a data-attribute to read it works as well. But right away you can see the next function error out since there is no data-attr to read.

See the full version here:

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
// highlight relevant menu item
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("stackoverflow") > -1) {
    $(".main-header--light").text("STACKOVERFLOW");
  }
  var tagName = $("#content").data("category").toLowerCase();
  $(".nav-item").each(function() {
    var menuItem = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    if (menuItem == tagName) {
      console.log(this);
      $(this).addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>HEADER - <span class="main-header--light"></span></h1>

<div id="content" data-category="Highlight This Item"></div>
<ul>
<li class="nav-item">11</li>
<li class="nav-item">2</li>
<li class="nav-item">Highlight This Item</li>
<li class="nav-item">44</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to understand what would be the best way to have this work consistently so that there are no errors present. I attempted an if else statement like so:

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
// highlight relevant menu item
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("stackoverflow") > -1) {
    $(".main-header--light").text("STACKOVERFLOW");
  }
  var tagName = $("#content").data("category").toLowerCase();
  $(".nav-item").each(function() {
    var menuItem = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    if (tagName === "undefined") {
      return false;
    } 
    else if (menuItem == tagName) {
      console.log(this);
      $(this).addClass("subnav-active");
    } else {};
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>HEADER - <span class="main-header--light"></span></h1>

<div id="content"></div>
<ul>
<li class="nav-item">11</li>
<li class="nav-item">2</li>
<li class="nav-item">34</li>
<li class="nav-item">44</li>
</ul>
```

Which from what I understand of `return: false;` and [How do I prevent, stop, or kill Javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684799/how-do-i-prevent-stop-or-kill-javascript-function) you can use it to not run a function and in this context, stop it from running the check and throwing the error in console.

What would be the best way around this to have a clean/slate no errors?

Comment: `$("#content").data("category")` or `$(this).text()` are null. Check if they are null prior to calling `.toLowerCase()`

Comment: Ok, I knew I had to check if it was null somehow first - didn't realize I needed to do it before calling that. I figured it would just be undefined irregardless even if I called it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So do not do it in one line, break it up into two.

```
var tagName = $("#content").data("category")
if (tagName) {
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
  $(".nav-item").each(function() {
    ...
  })
}
```

Comment: Potentially with some added trimmage if necessary

Comment: gotcha. Knew I needed to check beforehand somehow but was unclear how.